# Google Sheets Row Number of nth Instance from a column in another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have used the following google sheets formulas to obtain the row number for the nth instance of cell k3 within column A.

```
=ArrayFormula(SMALL(IF($A$4:$A$20000=K3,ROW($A$4:$A$20000)-MIN(ROW($A$4:$A$20000))+4),n))
```

I also used the following formula but it only works for the 1st instance.

```
MATCH(K3,A4:A20000,0)+ROW(A4:A20000)-1
```

I need to get the row number of the nth instance but for a range in another spreadsheet. I have tried replacing every instance of $A$4:$A$20000 in the 1st formula above with the string below but to no avail. I also tried it without the IMPORTRANGE().

```
IMPORTRANGE("myurl","mysheetname!$A$4:$A$20000")
```

Please help me to get that row number. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=filter(row(A4:A2000),A4:A2000=K3,countifs(A4:A2000,A4:A2000,row(A4:A2000),"<="&row(A4:A2000))=K4)
```

Where cell K3 is what you're looking for and K4 is the instance number (which you can hard code if you want).

[image]

**Update for your sample sheet:**

To bring in the data from another sheet, load it into your final sheet rather than trying to put the `importrange()` in the formula:

[image]

Then the formula in cell `A9` can reference the imported range (identifying the row number for the second instance of "BAG1"):

```
=filter(row(A2:A6),A2:A6="BAG1",countifs(A2:A6,A2:A6,row(A2:A6),"<="&row(A2:A6))=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your formula while editing it to access the range from the other spreadsheet but it also gets N/A in the cell. Need to access another spreadsheet.

Comment: If you're setting the range to `A4:A20000`, as per your initial example, make sure your other sheet has at least as many rows. May be better to set your range to `'Other Sheet'!A4:A`

Comment: Hey, I tried it but still no luck. Might need to look into the query and importrange combo or something

Comment: Can you share a mock sheeet?

Comment: Yes, how would I do that and it would need to be two connected sheets?

Comment: Create two dummy sheets (linked) and set the sharing on each to be 'Anyone with the link' to 'Viewer', then post both URLs.

Comment: Ok. These are the two file names and links.

Data file
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gdkf36seNcNZxyUIGL7alf-ISYznm5v8W_XWvja2aj4/edit?usp=sharing

Exact to here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sYnb-AFkxcOPzzSPxyMrluapkM14LqyL-fsxpZBijTY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, see update above.

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid just accessing it from the final sheet mainly because the data spreadsheet automatically adds a new sheet every week and I have a way to access the 1st instance automatically from each and every sheet. I might have to get it checking two columns, since each instance has other aspects I can lookup

Comment: I put my solution below. It is a workaround from the original question but it suits me just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work...

```
=VLOOKUP("BAG1"&3,IMPORTRANGE(url,Sheet1!A2:C6),3).
```

It finds the instance of BAG1 that has 3 in the neighbouring column and then retrieves the value in column 3.